AgentExecutor runs on loop - Ollama. llama3.2 and react_agent
Trying to build one text to sql project. I'm using ollama llama3.2 locally. But my model is slow and it keep on running sometimes without giving the result. Sometimes it generates query but not able to extract the query result.
from langchain_community.llms import Ollama
from db import get_schema, db
from langchain_community.agent_toolkits import create_sql_agent
from langchain_community.agent_toolkits.sql.toolkit import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from langchain_ollama import OllamaLLM
from langchain.agents import AgentType
from langchain_community.tools.sql_database.tool import QuerySQLDataBaseTool, InfoSQLDatabaseTool, ListSQLDatabaseTool, QuerySQLCheckerTool
from langchain_community.embeddings import OllamaEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_core.example_selectors import SemanticSimilarityExampleSelector
from langchain_core.prompts import FewShotPromptTemplate, PromptTemplate, ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_core.prompts import SystemMessagePromptTemplate
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, create_react_agent


llm = OllamaLLM(model="llama3.2")
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=llm)

embeddings = (
    OllamaEmbeddings(model = "llama3.2")
)

examples = [
    {   "input": "List all actors.", 
        "query": "SELECT * FROM Actor;"
    },
    {
        "input": "Find all movies of Ed Chase",
        "query": "SELECT film.title, concat(actor.first_name, ' ', actor.last_name) as actorname from film LEFT JOIN filmactor on film.film_id=filmactor.film_id LEFT JOIN actor on actor.actor_id=filmactor.actor_id WHERE concat(actor.first_name, ' ', actor.last_name) LIKE '%Ed Chase%'"
    },
    {
        "input": "Find all customers for the postal code 35200.",
        "query": "SELECT first_name,last_name,address_id FROM customer WHERE address_id = (SELECT address_id FROM address WHERE postal_code = '35200');",
    },
    {
        "input": "Find full address of Mary Smith.",
        "query": "SELECT address, address2, district, postal_code from address where address_id = (select address_id from customer where concat(first_name,' ', last_name) LIKE '%Mary Smith%');",
    },
    {
        "input": "How many customers are there",
        "query": 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer',
    },
    {
        "input": "Find the total number of actors.",
        "query": "SELECT COUNT(DISTINT(actor_id)) FROM Actor;",
    },
    {
        "input": "Who are the top 5 customers by total purchase?",
        "query": "SELECT customer.customer_id AS customer_id, concat(customer.first_name, ' ', customer.last_name) as customer_name, SUM(payment.amount) AS TotalPurchase FROM payment LEFT JOIN customer on customer.customer_id=payment.customer_id GROUP BY customer.customer_id ORDER BY TotalPurchase DESC LIMIT 5;",
    },
]

example_selector = SemanticSimilarityExampleSelector.from_examples(
    examples,
    embeddings,
    FAISS,
    k=3,
    input_keys=["input"],
)

sql_db_query =  QuerySQLDataBaseTool(db = db)
sql_db_schema =  InfoSQLDatabaseTool(db = db)
sql_db_list_tables =  ListSQLDatabaseTool(db = db)
sql_db_query_checker = QuerySQLCheckerTool(db = db, llm = llm)


tools = [sql_db_query, sql_db_schema, sql_db_list_tables, sql_db_query_checker]

# matched_queries = example_selector.vectorstore.search("How many actors are there?", search_type = "mmr")


# for tool in tools:
#     print(tool.name + " - " + tool.description.strip() + "\n")

system_prefix = """
Answer the following questions as best you can. You have access to the following tools:

{tools}

Use the following format:

Question: the input question you must answer
Thought: you should always think about what to do
Action: the action to take, should be one of [{tool_names}]
Action Input: the input to the action 
Observation:
the result of the action 
... (this Thought/Action/Action Input/Observation can repeat N times)
Thought: I now know the final answer
Final Answer: the final answer to the original input question 

Here are some examples of user inputs and their corresponding SQL queries:
"""

suffix = """
Begin!

Question: {input} 
Thought:{agent_scratchpad}
"""

dynamic_few_shot_prompt_template = FewShotPromptTemplate(
    example_selector = example_selector,
    example_prompt=PromptTemplate.from_template(
        "User input: {input}\nSQL query: {query}"
    ),
    input_variables=["input"],
    prefix=system_prefix,
    suffix=suffix
)


full_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        SystemMessagePromptTemplate(prompt=dynamic_few_shot_prompt_template),
    ]
)

# prompt_val = full_prompt.invoke(
#     {
#         "input": "How many actors are there?",
#         "tool_names" : [tool.name for tool in tools],
#         "tools" : [tool.name + " - " + tool.description.strip() for tool in tools],
#         "agent_scratchpad": [],
#     }
# )
# print(prompt_val.to_string())


agent = create_react_agent(llm, tools, full_prompt)
agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True, handle_parsing_errors=True)
des = agent_executor.invoke({"input": "How many actors are there?"})


print(des)

Error: Runs on loop and not extracting output [In this case '200' is the answer], sometimes not even correct answer.
Entering new AgentExecutor chain...

Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor;[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there? 
Thought: Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there? 
Thought: I need to execute a query that counts the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there?
Thought: I need to count the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there? 
Thought: I want to execute a SQL query that counts the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there? 
Thought: I should use the sql_db_query tool to execute a SQL query that counts the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there? 
Thought: I need to use the sql_db_query tool to execute a SQL query that counts the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there? 
Thought: I need to count the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there?
Thought: Execute a SQL query that counts the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there? 
Thought: I want to execute a SQL query that counts the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there?
Thought: I need to use the sql_db_query tool to execute a SQL query that counts the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there? 
Thought: I need to use the sql_db_query tool to execute a SQL query that counts the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there? 
Thought: Execute a SQL query to count the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there? 
Thought: I need to use the sql_db_query tool to execute a SQL query that counts the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)]Question: How many actors are there? 
Thought: I should use the sql_db_query tool to execute a SQL query that counts the number of distinct actor IDs.
Action: sql_db_query
Action Input: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) FROM Actor[(200,)] 


{'input': 'How many actors are there?', 'output': 'Agent stopped due to iteration limit or time limit.'} 

